# Converting GeoJSON to shapefile in Python with Fiona: problem with Geometry Collection

Tags: python, fiona

I have a function, using the Fiona package, to convert a GeoJSON to their respective shapefiles (going to figure out later to get merge them back together later on) However the problem is the GeoJSON, multiple geometries. And this causes the following error. So according to this I need to create a layer for each:

```
Geometry type of 'Geometry Collection' not supported in shapefiles.  Type can be overridden with a layer creation option of SHPT=POINT/ARC/POLYGON/MULTIPOINT/POINTZ/ARCZ/POLYGONZ/MULTIPOINTZ/MULTIPATCH.
```

What should I do here?

Also of note this GeoJSON can only have two types (technically three with geometry collection) Polygon & MultiPolygon. So everything should turn up in one shapefile later on.

```
import fiona
from fiona.crs import from_epsg

 def convert_json_to_shapefile(fc_file):
       total_start_time = start_time_measure()
       start_time = start_time_measure(
       'opening geojson file')
       export_folder = os.path.join("exported_data","geographic_information","details","shapefile")
        # First, we load the JSON file, and create a var to hold the data
       with open(fc_file) as f:
            fc_data = json.load(f)
    
        # Create export folder if it doesn't exist
       if not os.path.exists(export_folder):
            os.makedirs(export_folder)
    
        # Iterate over each feature
       total_num_features = len(fc_data['features']) - 1
       for num, feature in enumerate(fc_data['features']):
            print(f"Parsing feature {num} of {total_num_features}")
            # Let's get some data from each feature
            gipod_id = feature['properties']['gipodId']
            reference = feature['properties']['reference']  # Replace slashes with dashes for path
            geo_type = feature['geometry']['type']
            geometry = feature['geometry']
    
    
            # Split the EPSG string, get the last value, convert to int and generate a Fiona EPSG
            split_epsg = int(feature['geometry']['crs']['properties']['name'].split('::')[-1])
            feat_epsg = from_epsg(split_epsg)
    
            # Print out the data
            print(f"GIPOD ID: {gipod_id} - Ref: {reference}")
            print(f"Geometry type: {geo_type}")
            print(f"Spatial reference: {feat_epsg}")
            print(feature['properties'])
            # Create a geometry schema
            geo_schema = {
                'geometry': geo_type,
            }
            # Export filename. For now we'll just use the gipod ID and ref
            print(str(reference))
            export_file = os.path.join(export_folder,
                                       f"Shapefile_ID{str(gipod_id)}.shp")
            print(f'Writing {export_file}...')
            with fiona.open(export_file, mode='w', driver='ESRI Shapefile', schema=geo_schema, crs=feat_epsg) as output:
                output.write(geometry)
            print('----------')

   print(f"Done! You can find your shapefiles in the {os.path.abspath(export_folder)} folder. :-) ")
```

Comment: If possible avoid going from a permissive format like GeoJSON to a constrained one like shapefile. You may be able to take the geometry collections apart in to separate features for each geometry.

Comment: How do I do that? The best I know I can do for now is using the explode geometries from the gdal command. But the thing is it also converts all my multi's to single polygon's. Good enough solution but considering we are using this data into design. We would like to keep it that way.